# How can you check if a `string` is empty in Solidity

Tags: solidity, string

How can you check if a type `string` is empty in Solidity?

For instance this would work when testing if a string was initialized to have no characters:

```
string public emptyStringTest = '';
```

or when you would like to test if a `mapping(bytes32 => string)` has a key that is initialized.

```
mapping(bytes32 => string) emptyStringTest;
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can convert the string into a type `bytes` and then check its length.

For example this will test if `emptyStringTest` is indeed an empty string:

```
bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(emptyStringTest); // Uses memory
if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
    // emptyStringTest is an empty string
} else {
    // emptyStringTest is not an empty string
}
```

Info on the [memory keyword](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#reference-types)