# Update struct from function only if parameters exists

Tags: solidity, struct

What's the appropriate way to update a struct via a function only if the parameters exist? For example

```
struct MyStruct {
  bytes32 someThing
  bytes32 someOtherThing
}

function updateStruct(bytes32 someThing, bytes32 someOtherThing) public {
  // get struct
  if (someThing) {
    struct.someThing = someThing;
  }
  if(someOtherThing) {
    struct.someOtherThing;
  }
}
```

I only want to update the fields of the struct if the argument is passed into the function. If it's `null` or `undefined` I don't want to update the struct with that value.

Comment: You can use `somethig.length>0` for your if condition.

Comment: But what if its not bytes32 ? @PrashantPrabhakarSingh

Comment: I guess I will post a solution as comment will be too long. :)

Comment: I am going to create separate functions for updating each different value

Comment: `If it's null or undefined` - this is not Javascript.

Comment: @goodvibration - null or undefined aren’t terms only used in JS. While they may not be  typical nomenclatures in solidity I think people will understand we are talking about something that has no value

Answer (score 0):

So since your function has 2 parameters, you always have to pass 2 arguments. Now it depends on the type of function argument.

**bytes32**, you can use:

```
if(something.length != "")
```

If you have **string**, you can convert it to bytes32,

```
bytes memory testSomething= bytes(something);
if(testSomething.lenght > O)
```

If you have **uint**,

```
if(something > 0)
```

In case of **address**:

```
if(something != 0x)
```

Comment: For bytes32 the length is always 32, so you cannot use length to check for null with bytes32. But you can compare to zero `if (something != 0) { }` (the same trick applies with the address type).

Also you cannot cast from bytes32 to bytes, if something is bytes32 then `bytes(something)` throws a compilation error.

Comment: @Ismael I was not asking to convert bytes32 to bytes, I was saying if you have string params you can convert it to bytes and then check for length, ref: [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11039/how-can-you-check-if-a-string-is-empty-in-solidity). I need to check for bytes32, I thought this will be same as converting string to bytes 32. Please update the answer if you have a solution to check for empty value of bytes32.