# Syntax: How do you require a string to be null (or anything but null)?

Tags: solidity, mapping, require

I want to make sure that when `doSomething()` is called, the string variable is always populated (that it can't be left blank):

```
    function doSomething (string hash) public {
        require(hash != null);
    }
```

Similarly, I want to make sure that when `doSomethingElse()` is called, the string is not already mapped to an address:

```
    mapping (string => address) public hashes;

    function doSomethingElse (string hash) public {
        require(hashes[hash] = null);
    }
```

I know `null` is not the correct syntax, but what is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in the first case I would check the string length

```
require(bytes(hash).length > 0);
```

in the second case just check against the void address

```
require(hashes[hash] == address(0x0));
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to @mirg's valid answer.

As you know, in Solidity variables are never `null`. Instead, if they are not initialized, they contain their default value. For example for `uint` this is `0`. So, whatever type you use, if it's not initialized its value is its default value.

This is a bit unclear when it comes to strings, but checking the `bytes` `length` seems to be the way to go. More answers for example here: [How can you check if a `string` is empty in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11039/how-can-you-check-if-a-string-is-empty-in-solidity)